graphs and the interception point, python
I am writing a program that allows me to express a DIFFERENT variable from two equations, build a graph (preferably it should be built based on the functions derived earlier with respect to the axes), then find the point of intersection of the graphs and output its coordinates [x, y] with the possibility of their subsequent use. Problem 1 - when deriving a variable from an equation, exponent, square etc. go as sqrt, exp, but for graphs we need np.sqrt.... Problem 2 - point of intersection, in general, how can you realize if the array is unknown?
# Исходная система уравнений

# (x ** 2) / 2 + y ** 2 - 1
# 2*y-exp(x)-x

# Вызов библиотек
from sympy import symbols, solve
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x, y = symbols('x y')

# Ввод уравнения для выражения y
expr_y = input("Введите уравнение для выражения y: ")
y_expr = solve(expr_y, y)
print("Выражение для y:", *y_expr)
y_var = y_expr[0]

# Ввод уравнения для выражения x
expr_x = input("Введите уравнение для выражения x: ")
x_expr = solve(expr_x, x)  # Changed from 'a' to 'x' for consistency
print("Выражение для x:", *x_expr)
x_var = x_expr[1]


# Создание массива значений x
x_values = np.linspace(-5, 5, 100000)

# Вычисление значений y в зависимости от x
y_values = x_values/2 + np.exp(x_values)/2
# [y_var.subs(x, val) for val in x_values]

# Создание массива значений a
x1_values = np.linspace(-1, 1, 100000)

# Вычисление значений a в зависимости от b
y1_values = (2 - 2*x1_values**2)**(1/2)
# [a_var.subs(b, val) for val in b_values]

# Построение графика
plt.title('Моя Шиза сделала так')

ax = plt.gca()
ax.spines['left'].set_position('center')
ax.spines['bottom'].set_position('center')
ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)

ax.set(xlim=(-10, 10), xticks=np.arange(-10, 10),
       ylim=(-10, 10), yticks=np.arange(-10, 10))

ax.plot(x_values, y_values, label='y = ' '+ str(y_var)')
ax.plot(y1_values, x1_values, label='x = ' '+ str(x_var)')

y = np.array(y_values)
y1 = np.array(y1_values)

# Находим точку пересечения графиков
if any(y1_values) == any(y_values):
    #print(x_values, y_values, x1_values, y1_values)
    int = np.intersect1d(y, y1, assume_unique=False, return_indices=False)
    print(int)
    print(y_values[0] == y1_values[0])
    print(set(y_values) & set(y1_values))
    print(y for y in y_values if y in y1_values)

else :
    print("no")
c = []
for i in y:
    if i in y1:
        c.append(i)
        break

print(c)

ax.legend()
ax.grid(True)
plt.show()

